# Add to ZIP option in context menu for WinRAR

Tags: windows, context-menu, winrar, shell-extensions

With WinRAR installed, by default, your context menu (Right-click on file) says something like "Add directory to *.rar archive".

It's very handy but not cooperating with other systems that handle zip, not rar format.

How do I remove "Add to .rar" and add "Add to .zip" shell extension for context menu in Windows?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

there is a option, you can set by going in setting..
Go to Options-> Settings-> Compression -> (Compression Profiles)Create Default-> Archive Format-> Select Zip-> Click Ok-> Again Ok----> You Are Done :)

Comment: Options where? WinRar?

Comment: what if you want both `rar` and `zip` options to show in context menu?

Answer (score 4):

**There is also another way to use an existing profile or create a new profile and add that new profile to the context menu without setting or changing your default profile:**

1) Right-click on the file you would like to ZIP.
2) Click 'Add to archive...' from the Context Menu.

***If you already have a profile set that you would like to use, such as 'Add to ZIP', then all you have to do is:***

4) Click the 'Profiles...' button.
5) Left-click the profile you want to add to the context menu to highlight it.
6) Click the 'Edit' button to the right.
7) Use the existing name or change it if you want.
8) If you want the context menu item to execute immediately, then check 'Immediate Execution' or leave it unchecked if you want it to pop-up the options box before processing.
9) Check 'Add to context menu' to add that profile directly to the context menu for future use.

***If you don't have a profile already set for ZIP files, then:***

4) Set all of the settings you want in the options dialogue to process these types of files when executed from the context menu.
5) In the General tab, click 'Profiles...' and select 'Save current settings to a new profile...'
6) Change the 'Profile name' to something more descriptive to let you know what it does. (e.g. 'Add to ZIP')
7) If you want the context menu item to execute immediately, then check 'Immediate Execution' or leave it unchecked if you want it to pop-up the options box before processing.
8) Check 'Add to context menu' to add that profile directly to the context menu for future use.

Comment: For step 9, is there a way to get rid of the profile from the context menu? I only see an option to add it

Answer (score 0):

Use "Add to archive" and define as the archive format `.zip`.

Other that this, use the default Windows shell .zip maker (`Send to > Zipped folder`).

To change the shell entry itself I would assume you would need to dig up the Registry and set the correct flags to be passed to WinRar...

Comment: Hint, WinRar is using a context menu handler (at least my version is) `{B41DB860-64E4-11D2-9906-E49FADC173CA}` and winrar32 `{B41DB860-8EE4-11D2-9906-E49FADC173CA}` -  seems to point to this .dll `C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\rarext.dll`

Comment: Yet want to see WinRar dialog after trying to send to zip, that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking, we need to use the Winrar > Options > Settings > Integration tab to fully disable the 'Context Menu Handler' by unchecking all the options.  Then create our own entries on `HKCR\*\Shell\My_WinRAR` with the correct comamnd line syntax to zip a file.  It won't be as elegant as using a DLL but it might work.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My_WinRAR]
"MUIVerb"="WinRAR_ZIP_EM_UP_By_KNUCKLE_DRAGGER"
"icon"="WINRAR.exe"
"Position"="Top"
"HasLUAShield"=""
"Extended"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My_WinRAR\command]
@="WINRAR MAGIC GOES HERE"
;
;
```

Comment: Might work? Have you tested it?

Comment: You will need to edit this part with the command you actually want to run.  `@="WINRAR MAGIC GOES HERE"`, what have you got so far ?

Answer (score 0):

To delete the menu items "WinRAR Archive" and "WinRAR ZIP Archive" in the context menu of Windows Explorer at the "New" sub-section, do the following:

1. With the Registry Editor, under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, you will see 2 keys:
   WinRAR and WinRAR.ZIP
2. Rename those to something else. For example, rename the first one to WinRAR_RenamedToExcludeFromContextMenu
   This will let you to easily revert to the original state later, if you change your mind.
3. That's it. Those entries are gone from the context menu.