# How to add an item named "Open in Explorer" to right-click context-menu after I have selected some text?

Tags: windows-explorer, context-menu, right-click

For Windows 7 and above, I constantly ran into a situation like: go to `THE_DIRECTORY` and do something. Every time I have to copy `THE_DIRECTORY` and use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to open an Explorer, and then paste the special string `THE_DIRECTORY` to the address box, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

How do I add an item named "Open in Explorer" to right-click context-menu after I have selected some text? I have already [searched HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/search/?q=copy%20string%20context%20menu), but without any luck. Could someone shed some light on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example of a shell extension from the example in [this thread.](https://superuser.com/questions/665679/add-to-zip-option-in-context-menu-for-winrar/705183#705183)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Open_in_Explorer]
"MUIVerb"="Open_in_Explorer_By_KNUCKLE_DRAGGER"
"icon"="Explorer.exe"
"Position"="Top"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Open_in_Explorer\command]
@="cmd /c start /wait /b powershell -command \"Clear-Host;$CLIPBOARD = PowerShell -NoProfile -STA -Command {[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('PresentationCore') | Out-Null;[Windows.Clipboard]::GetText()};C:\\Windows\\Explorer.exe $CLIPBOARD\""
;
```

Still working on how to make the magic happen, I think powershell maybe has a `[Windows.Clipboard]::GetText()` method we can use.